# Light of laser doesn't spread?

Tags: visible-light, laser

How exactly can a combination of monochromaticity and coherent light make a light not want to spread out? When it's all one wavelength and it's all amplified it should make the light brighter and thus more energetic. I can't seem to understand why the light doesn't spread normally.

Comment: What kind of laser are you talking about here, laser light does suffer from spread like any other light source.

Comment: Laser light does not spread out like any other lightsource though? If it would, then there'd be nothing special about it. Any laser has monochromaticity and coherency which creates a 'line' of light. @Triatticus

Comment: And I'm saying you read this in a textbook or online somewhere, because it sounds like they are discussing a theoretically perfect laser, not a real laser here in the real world.

Comment: Well, no. And I know that not **all** light can be kept together and some of it will spread out, but that's hard to see with the naked eye. @Triatticus

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam - laser beams most certainly spread. Your statement on the light being brighter and thus more energetic has no bearing on laser propagation through space (but may impact propagation through materials that can be damaged by the beam).

Comment: Yeah they spread but not like normal light. I don't get how though that's the question and it's not clear from the link you provided @JonCuster

Comment: Sorry my second comment wasn't meant to sound accusatory, it was supposed to ask if you had read this/ heard this somewhere. As Jon points out laser light does spread like any other light source. In fact it can be quite obvious over long distances. Commercial lasers usually have information on their beam divergence listed somewhere by the manufacturer (will depend on how detailed the packaging is).

Comment: Hey, no problem. It doesn't actually matter to me how much it does or does not spread, I'm just trying to figure out how the light is contained together and why it doesn't spread 100% like normal visible light would. @Triatticus

Comment: You can collimate 'normal' light just fine, and get near-Gaussian optics. You just end up throwing away a lot of it that is not in the specific mode you create. The point is that a laser, by how it works, makes a lot of beam in a well defined mode so you don't waste a lot of it creating a collimated beam - it already is by design.

Comment: The question assumes that the low divergence is DUE to coherence and monochromaticity but this is not true. You can have a divergent monochromatic beam or make a laser beam divergent.

Comment: The specialness of laser light is twofold: (1) All one wavelength, and (2) Extremely small [_etendue_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) (the ability to be focused onto an extremely small point or, into a thin ray.) In the old days, light with property (1) was made with a color filter that threw away all unwanted wavelengths, and for property (2), a _spatial filter_ that threw away all unwanted rays. In other words, throw away _most_ of the light from your source. But a laser doesn't waste any energy _making_ unwanted wavelengths or unwanted rays in the first place.

Comment: I think this is a very good question, given the fact that you can find quite a few sources ([example](https://www.msnucleus.org/membership/html/k-6/as/technology/5/ast5_1a.html)) that claim that coherent light spreads out less than incoherent light.

Answer (score 22):

If you take a light source such as a hot filament (not a laser) and put the filament one focal length away from a parabolic reflector, then you will get an accurately collimated beam if the filament is small compared to the focal length. This is the sort of thing that happens in searchlights (though depending on type they might use an arc or some other source rather than a filament).

To get this collimation, however, the source has to be small in length and width, and this means it is hard to get a bright collimated beam this way. Also you have to position the source accurately relative to the reflector. So it is hard in practice to get as good collimation as you can quite easily from a laser, but it is not impossible. In this sense lasers are no better collimated than other light sources could in principle be if they were engineered carefully. It is just that the collimation is a whole lot easier to achieve for a laser without compromising on brightness.

The ultimate limit to collimation of a light beam is called the *diffraction limit*. For a beam of width $w$ and wavelength $\lambda$ the diffraction limit is approximately given by the angle
$$
\theta \simeq \frac{\lambda}{w}
$$
(you can multiply this by a $1.22$ if you like).
This is angular spread of the beam. This limit comes from the wave nature of light, so no matter what the source (laser or not), a beam of width $w$ will, at a large distance $L$ from the start point, have spread out to a width at least
$$
\theta L = \frac{\lambda}{w} L.
$$
No light source can do better than this. Most light sources do a lot worse. Lasers often get close to it because their internal manufacture typically requires accurate mirrors at each end of the laser cavity, and the amplification process favours one particular spatial configuration of the light.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the Gaussian distribution of intensity within the beam, which IIRC does most of the work suppressing the diffraction.

Comment: Etendue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue